# Demo applications build with CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, demo

I've been learning how to work with CodeIgniter for a few weeks now, but I'm a little stuck on how to build a real application with it.

Are there any open source demo's that I could use to see how the flow works in there.
Couldn't find anything on Google.

Comment: I have used codeigniter for about 2 years. I think it is quite straight forward to build on it to create whatever real app? By the what do you mean by stuck? May be we can help with that part better

Comment: @shawndreck It's more like the entire flow of an application, that's why I'm looking for some demo of a real app to get the hang of it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Getting Started with CodeIgniter and How to Create All Those Great Apps:](http://devsnippets.com/article/getting-started-with-codeigniter-and-how-to-create-all-those-great-apps.html)
Contains 12 easy to follow tutorials to build small apps!

4.1 Build an RSS 2.0 Feed with CodeIgniter
4.2 Generating PDF files using CodeIgniter
4.3 Building a Shopping Cart using CodeIgniter’s Shopping Cart Class
4.4 CodeIgniter Clan Site- Part1 & Part2
4.5 Validating Web Forms with the Code Igniter
4.6 A sample Facebook application with CodeIgniter
4.7 CodeIgniter and Ajax Using JQuery Tutorial
4.8 Real Live Search with Pagination
4.9 How to Update your Twitter Status with CodeIgniter
4.10 Codeigniter Event Calendar
4.11 Live search with CodeIgniter and Mootools
4.12 Creating a File Hosting Site with CodeIgniter

Comment: @gloomy-penguin please edit my answer and cross out which are dead so all can benefit of this info.

Answer (score 3):

Get a look at the following scripts and apps created by CodeIgniter on hotscripts.com.

http://www.hotscripts.com/search/all-scripts/codeigniter

Answer (score 3):

Please use this github project for demo Codeigniter CMS Aplication
https://github.com/daylightstudio/FUEL-CMS/tree/master/fuel

Answer (score 3):

I looked around a bit and I found this site http://qoodles.phpfogapp.com/ it was built with codeigniter and the source code is on github: https://github.com/hush2/qoodles